# GWT Servlet error com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc .StatusCodeException: 404 on Tomcat server

Tags: gwt, tomcat, servlets, rpc

1) Installed GWT and Eclipse on Mac

2) Created a GWT project (2.4) with generated code called Hello

3) Ran the project on local computer (in dev mode) and it works as expected.

4) Compile the project and upload the war directory to my account hosted by serversanddomains.com

- The production front end works fine, but when I try the RPC request I get the following error.

com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 404 
Not Found 
The requested URL /hello/greet was not found on this server.

I tried compiling with different versions of java as suggest by [How to use GWT - RPC to Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354802/how-to-use-gwt-rpc-to-tomcat-server)

Serversanddomains.com currently runs Tomcat and java 1.6.0_29

I asked to see the error log and they responded 
Here is the error we are seeing in the error log:
File does not exist: /home/username/public_html/hello/greet, referer: http://mydomain.com/Hello.html
And in the /usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/logs/catalina.out log file no reports of anything.

My web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">


  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.hello.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Hello.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Any suggests would be welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, shared hosting accounts are usually just apache virtual hosts. Apache is just a `web server`. To host a GWT app that uses RPC, you need an `application server`, like [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) (used by GWT Dev Mode), [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/) and others.

You will NEVER be able to do that from a shared hosting account, because it's just not possible. You need to get a VPS dedicated server and set everything up yourself, usually.

Comment: Thank you,  I contacted the provider and you are correct.  I will have to update the package I have.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is not set up to be a servlet container.  It does not know how to serve /hello/greet, which your GWT app defines in web.xml.

You should ask your host if they offer hosting that supports this sort of java servlet environment.

Comment: Thank you Riley,  I just sent a ticket to serversanddomains.com and will let you know the response.