# Deploying GWT RPC app in Tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, servlets, rpc

As per the Google tutorial, I have developed the basic StockWatcher application, that makes an RPC call to the server, which sends some data, which is displayed on the client.

I now want to deploy it in Tomcat, such that if call something like `localhost/StockWatcher`, I should get the same experience as when running the app from GWT in development mode.

How do I do this? There is a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354802/how-to-use-gwt-rpc-to-tomcat-server), but I couldn't much understand it. If I only copy the compiled `war` folder, what happens to the `GreetingServiceImpl` class which handles the RPC? And how do I do the mapping such that `localhost/StockWatcher` maps to `localhost:8080` (something like `Mod_Rewrite`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to deploy war on TOMCAT

```
    1)Compile you gwt web application
    2)Copy  the war file 
    3)Add all libraries(jar files) in lib folder of war file 
    4)Rename your war as "myapp"
    5)create a .war file with that "myapp" folder
    6)start tomcat with catalina.bat run.
```

For step5 (generating .war file ):[Preparing .war file from command line](http://www.coderanch.com/t/400585/java/java/war-file)

Comment: I couldn't understand step 3. The `lib` folder in `war` already contains many `jar` files, including `gwtquery jar`. What other `jar` file do I need to add?

Comment: By the way, by `lib` in `war`, you meant `lib` within `WEB-INF` within `war`, right?

Comment: Ok .I am just making sure.just cross check once :)

Comment: How do I compile the web app?

Comment: Kaustav,seems that should be an another question i think.what do you say?.

Comment: Never mind, got it! I didn't much understand all this `war` file stuff. The project comes with a `war` folder. Initially it doesn't contain much, after doing compile through Eclipse, it contains a `StockWatcher` folder. I now take this `war` folder's contents, place it in `ROOT` of `Tomcat`, and hit `localhost:8080/StockWatcher.html`, and bingo, it works!

Comment: However, if  I want to get the same result when I hit `localhost:/Stockwatcher`, I think I will have to do some URL rewriting. Where do I do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24870/discussion-between-the-suresh-atta-and-cupidvogel)

Comment: Yeah, I knew how to compile, but I am used to seeing only a `war` folder, I didn't know how to export it to a `.war` file`...I thought that may be it would be different..

Comment: I forgot that you using only one view .

Comment: So how do I do the URL mapping?

Comment: If you are using single view why you need url rewriting ??

Comment: I don't like the `localhost:8080` bit...:) It is not absolutely necessary, but still it would be good to learn it now..

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you deploy well your war directory and you are able to start tomcat you have done everything. If you access your page using this url : localhost:8080/StockWatcher gwt will know that it must use that url as a baseURL for all gwt/rpc requests.

To generate the war using Eclipse : right click on the project -> export -> war. You will have the war exported with all the dependencies inside. just unzip it in the ROOT directory

Comment: Okay, so suppose I get the `.war` file. I take it to `ROOT`, unzip it. Then what?

Comment: Then, you run tomcat that's all what you need to do.